# Google Drive's "Download zip" adds .txt extension to plain text files

Tags: google-drive-api, zip, plaintext

While experimenting with Google Drive SDK, I noticed a possibly unwanted behaviour of the Google Drive web interface.

When downloading an entire folder as a *zip* file, some files within that folder with MIME `text/plain` appear in the zip with added extension `.txt`, even if their extension is different on Drive.
For example, I had some `.conf` and `.asc` files, which ended being `.conf.txt` and `.asc.txt` in the resulting compressed archive, respectively.

The issue seems to exist only when using the "Download zip" feature: if the files are downloaded from the web interface one by one or using the SDK the extension is the original, as expected.

Comment: I've reproduced this and filed a bug with the team. Voting to move this to 'SuperUser' though, since it isn't really about the SDK.

Comment: @DanMcGrath thank you! I hope the issue will be solved rapidly.  In fact, I wasn't sure where to ask the question, so I'm happy you voted to move it to the right place.

Comment: Not solved so far...

Comment: I just wasted two hours on this, because windows helpfully does not show the new ".txt" extension so one does not even know it is there. This is almost four months old. Very disappointing.

Comment: Hey @DanMcGrath , are there plans to fix this any time soon? Is there a Google product forum which will be more appropriate to post/ask about this?

Comment: @sillyfly - I'm no longer on the Drive team, but I posted a question on the bug to see if there is an update (it's blocked on a system migration). There is a Drive product forum that you can ask this question on: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/drive

Comment: This bug is still not fixed, killed an hour of time, it appended `.jpg` to image resources, which my app file structure did not intend!

Comment: this is the dumbest bug I have ever seen on google products!

Comment: The bug is still there, 3 years later. Lovely

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you can download all your files from Google Drive, but instead of using the browser,

1. Go to https://www.google.com/drive/download/
2. Install Google Drive Sync executable
3. Log into whichever Google account that has your files
4. Open Windows Explorer and find where your Google Drive is mapped.  You should see an icon like the following:

[image]

5. Double-click the Google Drive icon and navigate to the folder you wish to download.  You should see links to your Google files, but non-Google files are downloaded and sync'ed with Google Drive Sync like the following:

[image]

6. Right-click to get the context menu and select the compression program.  E.g., I have 7-zip installed, so I selected 7-Zip > Add to "your_file.zip"

This will compress the files without adding any weird file extensions.  I haven't tried this on Mac or other compression programs.  I believe this should work for any file extension since the files are downloaded to your hard drive.

Note, you can select which folders to sync, in case you have folders that were shared with you.  This prevents huge downloads, large sync times and allows you to only download and sync only what you need.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The same situation with ZIP archives. I use the usual ZIP scheme to store files, but with a different extension *.tec. Before downloading the archive, Google rigidly renames the files to *.tec.zip!

I don't see any solution other than to programmatically check the files for the "zip" extension and rename them before opening. Of course, it's a problem that my product has to fix Google's bugs, but there it is...